# Where to find backend of 404 page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, http-status-code-404, event-tracking

I'm trying to find the backend of the 404 page of our site: `http://www.australiancriminallawyers.com.au`. We are using Wordpress.

I need to trace its backend and look into changing the Google Analytics tracking code. Currently, the tracking code is the same as the code present on all pages which is implemented via the header.php file.

I already looked into the theme files but there is no 404.php file. Where can this 404 error message be originating from?

Further, how do I make it happen so that the 404 page does not make use of the same tracking code present on other valid pages (I need to modify just the tracking code on the 404 page for event tracking)?

An example of a wrong URL that prompts a 404 error message is `http://www.australiancriminallawyers.com.au/web`.

Comment: Which theme you using?

Comment: @batz Thanks for the feedback. We're using Evolve for the theme.

Comment: You could alter the code using JavaScript, Google Tag Manager or in plain, old PHP. The 404 pages in WP are dynamically generated, if I recall correctly, like all pages.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you looking for, But  you wan to track pages creates 404 errors with Yoast SEO plugin https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/google-analytics/tracking-downloads-error-pages/

Comment: We could do that and am almost sure it will solve the problem (our other site makes use of this plugin and it doesn't have this issue). We will also most likely have to create a 404.php file first. But then this doesn't solve my current confusion over where to find the origin of the 404 error message on this site. I really want to understand how it works.

Comment: Could be its inside a folder "templates" instead of Main folder?

Comment: Found it on index.php. But it comes with a bunch of other codes. I'm not sure if there's a way to isolate its tracking code from those on other pages. Creating a 404.php file seems to be the only way and then make some code adjustments later.